# What's the best way of searching for Flash content in git repositories?

Tags: git, flash

Given that Flash is now obsolete, I want to search a bunch of git repositories to look for where we might have stored Flash content so that we can expunge it. I know how to search git, but the question is: what kind of patterns should I look for in the repositories?

For example, if I were looking for PDFs then I could search for `%PDF` as a string. Are there such signatures that stand out for Flash content?

Comment: Worth adding as an answer, rather than a comment, so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [SWF file format specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf#page=27) or [this older spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec-v10.pdf#G5.88780) flash files (`*.swf`) start with `FWS`, `CWS` or `ZWS` headers (`SWF`, `SWC` and `SWZ` spelled backward).

Flash Video (`*.flv`) start with `FLV`. Not sure about Flash Audio (`*.fla`).

[Here is](https://github.com/threatstack/libmagic/blob/master/magic/Magdir/flash) source code for `libmagic`, it lists the same headers and nothing more.